# How to access function another model in loopback?

Tags: node.js, post, loopbackjs, loopback

I have two model Place and Tag. I created creteTag() remote methode in tag.js and I would like to access this functinon in place.js.

**tag.js**

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function(Tag) {
Tag.crateaTag = function(name, callback) {
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/tags',
        body:{
            "name": name
        },
        json: true
     },
     function (error, response,body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
           console.log('Hiba' + error + ' \n' + response);
        }
        callback(error, body);
     });
};
```

**place.js**

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function(Place) {
var app = require('../../server/server');
Place.createPlace = function(name, descreption, tagName, callback) {
    var Tag = app.models.Tag; //???

    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/tags',
        body:{
            "name": name,
            "descreption": descreption,
            "tag": Tag.createTag(tagName) //???
        },
        json: true
     },
     function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
           console.log('Hiba' + error + ' \n' + response);
        }
        callback(error, body);
     });
  };
};
```

I would like to post the tag that I would like to see separate collection in my db.

Comment: you don't need to add your function `crateaTag` in tag.js because this function is already available in persistent model. No need for `request` in place.js because you can use native `Place.app.models.tag.create()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **tag.js** declare `crateaTag`  as remote method:

```
Tag.remoteMethod('crateaTag', {
accepts: {
    arg: 'name',
    type: 'string',
    required: true
    },
    description: "create a tag"
});
```

In **place.js** use `Tag` as:

```
var Tag = app.models.Tag;
Tag.createTag('test', function(){
// do your stuff
});
```